# Evaluate two "DD-MM" strings as date and calculate before or after

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am attempting to evaluate whether three dates are before or after each other and also if they are this year given the current DD-MM

Example

```
var firstPayment = moment('18-01', 'DD-MM');
var secondPayment = moment('18-07', 'DD-MM');
var todayDate = moment(10-02, 'DD-MM');


if(todayDate.isAfter(firstPayment) && todayDate.isBefore(secondPayment)) {
     lastInterestPaymentDate.text(firstPayment.add(-1,'years').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
     nextInterestPaymentDate.text(secondPayment.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
} else {
     nextInterestPaymentDate.text(secondPayment.add(1,'years').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
     lastInterestPaymentDate.text(firstPayment.format('DD MMM YYYY')); //add(1, 'years').
}
```

The issue is that if the statement evaluates true the dates order correctly however if the firstPayment is `18-01` then the outputted date should be `18-01-2015` but if the firstPayment is `18-11` then it should output as `18-11-2014`

I hope this makes some sense as I am really stuck

Comment: What situations are valid?  Today before firstpayment + Today before lastpayment?  Today after firstpayment + today before lastpayment?  Today equals firstpayment and today before lastpayment?  Spell it out because your IF is only checking one of six possible conditions and then dumping the other five into the ELSE.

Comment: Good question… if Today is the ```10-02``` and the firstPayment is ```18-01``` and secondPayment is ```18-07``` then the conditional evaluates as true and so lastInterestPayment = ```18-01-2015``` and nextInterestPayment = ```18-07-2015```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need to figure out the logic better - perhaps this can be condensed but here is a full `if` block containing all possible conditions that you'd need to flesh out.

```
if(todayDate.isAfter(firstPayment)) {
  if (todayDate.isBefore(secondPayment)) {
    lastInterestPaymentDate.text(firstPayment.add(-1,'years').format('DD MMM YYYY'));
    nextInterestPaymentDate.text(secondPayment.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  } else if (todayDate.isAfter(secondPayment)) {
    // ??
  } else {  // todayDate equals secondPayment
    // ??
  }
} else if (todayDate.isBefore(firstPayment)) {
  if (todayDate.isBefore(secondPayment)) {
    // ??
  } else if (todayDate.isAfter(secondPayment)) {
    // ??
  } else {  // todayDate equals secondPayment
    // ??
  }    
} else {  // todayDate is equal to firstPayment
  if (todayDate.isBefore(secondPayment)) {
    // ??
  } else if (todayDate.isAfter(secondPayment)) {
    // ??
  } else {  // todayDate equals secondPayment
    // ??
  }
}
```

As you can see my comment above is wrong, there are nine conditions not six.

Comment: This got me to the right place in the end, thanks for your response and guidance. I eventually used the above with ```console.log()``` statements for each condition and mapped it through.

Answer (score 1):

You could evaluate only the months part of firstPayment and todayDate, and decide if you should subtract 1 year.

```
if (todayDate.month() < firstPayment.month())
    firstPayment.add(-1, 'years');
```

**Edit:**

Elaborating a bit more, and if I understood you, I would check for the month in your else statement. Please check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/7kjfakzy/

In the meanwhile I made an alternate version, which I think is more what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/m826med2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, given the code above where would you process this conditional?

Comment: I made two examples, one based on the first answer I gave, and another example which tries to simplify the problem. I am assuming you always want to order the dates like `lastInterestPayment (firstPayment)  -> today -> nextInterestPayment (secondPayment)`

Comment: Thanks again and I think you are close but if you use the value of ```28-04``` for firstPayment and ```28-10``` for secondPayment you will notice that its is putting ```28-04``` as the last payment and ```28-10``` as the next where in fact the reverse should be true.

Comment: firstPayment: 28-04, secondPayment: 28-10 means that 28-10 is the last payment (28-10-2014) and 28-04 is the next payment (28-10-2015)? I don't follow that logic. You mean that the order of the payments is not relevant? I thought that firstPayment should correspond to the last payment you made and the secondPayment should correspond to the next payment (is not paid yet).

Comment: Please try to explain better the meanings of the payments (first, second, last and next), with multiple scenarios.